M-RET does not do what is documented in org mode guide
Environment
My emacs is GNU Emacs 29.4. I use it in a terminal emulator, iTerm2. I am on macOS Sonoma 14.5.
Problem
M-RET, M-S-RET, M-LEFT, M-RIGHT does not do what is documented in the org mode guide, https://orgmode.org/guide/Structure-Editing.html.
Other than that, I can use my Left Option key like a Meta key. (an iTerm Setting allows that.)*
How can I achieve the set of the functionalities that is defined in the guide linked above?
Findings

Checked what function the key combination bound to. C-h k M-RET yields ~3 in the buffer.

However, M-x org-meta-return enters a new heading before that. So, the function is there and works.

Checked what key the function is bound to C-h a org-meta-return shows a page M-RET is listed, but not unexpected C-RET as it seems to be working:
org-meta-return               C-c C-x m, C-c C-x RET, M-RET                                         |
Insert a new heading or wrap a region in a table.

Also, M-RET, and M-S-RET functionality seems to work with C-RET, and C-S-RET instead, respectively: They add new heading and todo element after the heading where point is at.


Configuration
I do not have any org-mode specific configuration other than:
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") #'org-store-link)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") #'org-agenda)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") #'org-capture)

*Also I am aware that Esc key can always be used for Meta, although not as press and hold but press.

In a terminal emulator, if you don't have a Meta key, instead of M-RET, you can use ESC RET and similarly for the arrow keys: ESC <right>, etc.
You cannot do everything you can do in the GUI, but you can go fairly far.
See Using Org on a TTY in the manual.

I have a Meta key. (iTerm2/Settings/Profiles/Keys/Left Option key: Esc+).
Thank you for the manual section.

Actually, checked and see, ESC RET behaves as M-RET, and so does the ESC  or other arrow keys. Thanks!

I can't parse your comment: does that mean that ESC RET and the rest work according to the documentation or not?

ESC RET behaves as M-RET is documented to behave. ESC <right>, ESC <left> and ESC <up>, and ESC <down> behave as corresponding M  correspondents are documented to behave. Thanks!

OK - thanks for clarifying. I still don't understand why you think you have a Meta key, if it's never passed to Emacs, but that's a mystery for another day. All I really care about is that the documentation is correct.

I do not understand why just one key binding is not there means I do not have Meta key. Conversely I use Meta for many key combinations in Emacs such as M-a, M-e, even to execute the command for this non existing keybinding with Meta, such as M-x org-meta-return.
About docs, 4. seems contrary to the docs.

My apologies: I misunderstood. I thought none of the M- combinations did anything. Are you saying that every such combination works except for M-RET, M-S-RET, M-<left>, and M-<right>? If so, it's probably the case that these (and only these) are intercepted by either the OS/desktop environment or the application (presumably ITerm2) and they are not passed on to Emacs. If that's the case, you might be able to undefine them at the higher layer. Check this question although it's Linux specific.

Meta in general works for me in Emacs in a terminal emulator provided it has a setting to make a key for example Left Option Esc+ (for Meta). Yes, they do work except those combinations you listed and M-<up> and M-<down>.

Then the ESC-RET etc seem to be the path of least resistance: you still get the operational effect and you don't have to go hunting to convince the OS/Desktop Env/App/Whoever to just pass the M-<mumble> combinations through to Emacs.

Exactly! Going to an emulator setting is already enough and out of the area I want my text editor to be configurable inside, going to some OS/Desktop etc. is terrible. But that is only my opinion. What I expect from a decent text editor is to work in my remote server box without hassles of OS-etc-specific-configs even in its config let alone outside of its config. However, emacs is a bit far away from that. There is already GUI app and no window disparity. It is not good in that respect.

You are misreading the situation: what do you expect Emacs to do if it is not given any input? That's exactly the situation here: the OS/Desktop/App under which Emacs is running, are interpreting M-RET in whatever way they want and not passing it on to Emacs - so how do you expect Emacs to be able to do anything about it? Anyway, end of discussion here: this is not a discussion site. If you have a question, put it in a new question.


C-h k M-RET yields ~3 in the buffer.

You are running Emacs inside of a terminal emulator. You generally can’t use M-RET in a terminal emulator at all; under normal circumstances terminal emulators tend to emulate the DEC VT100 and subsequent terminals which had no use for that key combination.
Some terminal emulators do have extended escape sequences for many or all key combinations that cannot otherwise be represented, but they aren’t standard and aren’t common. If you use xterm, search the documentation for modifyOtherKeys. If you use some other terminal emulator then I can’t help you; you’ll have to consult its documentation on your own.
Or you could just run the Emacs gui like a normal person.

Yes, you are right that I am using a Terminal emulator. I want to use emacs in a Terminal emulator to be able to use it wherever a unix terminal is available without the need of a gui, like a normal text editor, e.g. vim.
I don't agree on your last line.
